# Gibberish string prepended to deleted text in the PDF obtained by compiling 'diff' file generated by latexdiff

Tags: strings, debugging, latexdiff, changes, bugs

I am using [`latexdiff`](https://ctan.org/pkg/latexdiff) for marking up corrections requested by the examiners to my PhD thesis. I have a strange issue with this.

Upon compiling the `diff.tex` file, I get a specific string `4.0pt=-.55ex` at the beginning of each deleted text throughout the document. See this figure.

[image: gibberish at beginning of deleted string]

In the source file `diff.tex`, the highlighted entires correspond to these lines

```
\DIFdelbegin \DIFdel{references are }\DIFdelend
\DIFdelbegin \DIFdel{\textbf{modified}}\DIFdelend
\DIFdelbegin \DIFdel{Creative Commons Attribution ...}\DIFdelend
\DIFdelbegin \DIFdel{they attribute it, that they :}\DIFdelend
\DIFdelbegin \DIFdel{that they do not alter, transform ...}\DIFdelend
```

The preamble generated by `latexdiff` for this `diff.tex` defines these commands as follows

```
\providecommand{\DIFdelbegin}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelend}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdel}[1]{{\protect\color{red}\sout{#1}}}  %DIF PREAMBLE
```

I have tried searching for the string `4.0pt=-.55ex` in the `diff.tex` file, but not even a portion of this exists anywhere! From where is this spurious string originating, and how do I get rid of this problem?

Comment: as always it would be much easier to help if you provided an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My crystal ball says that you are redefining \ULdepth:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{ulem}
\renewcommand\ULdepth{4.0pt} %<--- wrong
\providecommand{\DIFdelbegin}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelend}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdel}[1]{{\protect\color{red}\sout{#1}}} 
\begin{document}
\DIFdelbegin \DIFdel{references are }\DIFdelend
\DIFdelbegin \DIFdel{\textbf{modified}}\DIFdelend
\DIFdelbegin \DIFdel{Creative Commons Attribution ...}\DIFdelend
\DIFdelbegin \DIFdel{they attribute it, that they :}\DIFdelend
\DIFdelbegin \DIFdel{that they do not alter, transform ...}\DIFdelend

\end{document}
```

Comment: @UlrikeFisher, happy new year. Prima facie, your crystal ball indeed seems to be correct. Only the underline based styles have a problem. I am already using the `ulem` package with this custom depth in my thesis. How can I make this work with the `underline` style provided by `latexdiff`?

Comment: @Krishna it's always wrong to redefine a length resgister with `\renewcommand` you should set the length with `\setlength` not redefine it so it is no longer a length. that is true in general not just for ulem or latexdiff.

Comment: Use `\setlength\ULdepth{4pt}` instead.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer and @DavidCarlisle thank you. However, this throws an error saying `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.5 \setlength{\ULthickness}{0.75pt}
`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you. Happy new year! I did not know this. Always have a chance to learn something new with latex.

Comment: @Krishna `\ULthickness` is a macro  which should be redefined with `\renewcommand`, not a length register,

Comment: \ULdepth and \ULthickness is not the same.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle and that fixes it all. Thanks to you both. Upvoted and accepted. With that, I am off to the London Eye for the fireworks :).